# How can I define a variable with another variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to save a list of audio files in javascript.

```
function save() {
   for(i=1; i<5; i++){
      s=document.getElementById("s"+i);
   };
}
```

The audio files are like this:

```
<audio id="s1"><source src="Sounds/s1.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s2"><source src="Sounds/s2.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s3"><source src="Sounds/s3.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s4"><source src="Sounds/s4.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

but untill s30.

How can I make variable s also change so I can save these audio files as different variables?

Comment: try to use array and push all newly generated 's' in that array you can have the all variable in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a object to store like a hashmap/properties or use a array to do this, see the examples bellow:

Object:

```js
function save() {
   var audios = {};
   for(i=1; i<5; i++){
      var id = "s"+i;
      audios[id] = document.getElementById(id);
   };
   return audios;
}


var audios = save();

console.log(audios["s2"]);
console.log(audios["s3"]);
```

```html
<audio id="s1"><source src="Sounds/s1.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s2"><source src="Sounds/s2.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s3"><source src="Sounds/s3.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s4"><source src="Sounds/s4.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Array:

```js
function save() {
   var audios = [];
   for(i=1; i<5; i++){
      var id = "s"+i;
      audios.push(document.getElementById(id));
   };
   return audios;
}


var audios = save();

console.log(audios[1]);
console.log(audios[2]);
```

```html
<audio id="s1"><source src="Sounds/s1.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s2"><source src="Sounds/s2.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s3"><source src="Sounds/s3.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s4"><source src="Sounds/s4.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Selecting all at once:

```js
var audio = document.querySelectorAll('audio');

console.log(audio[0]);
console.log(audio[1]);
console.log(audio[2]);
console.log(audio[3]);
```

```html
<audio id="s1"><source src="Sounds/s1.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s2"><source src="Sounds/s2.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s3"><source src="Sounds/s3.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s4"><source src="Sounds/s4.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an id in HTML automatically creates a variable in the global scope, so you don't need to create them yourself.

This pollutes the global scope, and it's better not to use ids.

Example:

```js
console.log(s1);
console.log(s2);
console.log(s3);
console.log(s4);
```

```html
<audio id="s1"><source src="Sounds/s1.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s2"><source src="Sounds/s2.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s3"><source src="Sounds/s3.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s4"><source src="Sounds/s4.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

A better solution is to use a class name to select all elements using [Document#querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and get an array (actually array like [**nodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)) of items:

```js
var audio = document.querySelectorAll('.audio');

console.log(audio[0]);
console.log(audio[1]);
console.log(audio[2]);
console.log(audio[3]);
```

```html
<audio class="audio"><source src="Sounds/s1.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio class="audio"><source src="Sounds/s2.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio class="audio"><source src="Sounds/s3.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio class="audio"><source src="Sounds/s4.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one line of code using [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll),to create an object `audios` to work with:

```js
var audios = document.querySelectorAll('audio');

// Audio ids, src
audios.forEach(function (el) {
  console.log(el.id, el.querySelector('source').src);
});

// All audios
console.log('audios:', audios);
```

```html
<audio id="s1"><source src="Sounds/s1.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s2"><source src="Sounds/s2.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s3"><source src="Sounds/s3.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s4"><source src="Sounds/s4.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
```

```html
<audio id="s1"><source src="Sounds/s1.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s2"><source src="Sounds/s2.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s3"><source src="Sounds/s3.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="s4"><source src="Sounds/s4.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Comment: tagname audio select and load variable audio.variable audio is type array object.