# How to genereted name for new variable (in loop for example)?

Tags: javascript

***How to genereted name for new variable (in loop for example)?***

```
for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; i <= m; i++) {

    var ? (i and j) = document.createElement("div");
    }
}
```

**New name is "i" + "j" from loop**

Comment: Why would you use separate variables instead of an array?

Comment: You can see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951786/how-can-i-define-a-variable-with-another-variable/47951827#47951827), you can use arrays/object/hashmap.

Comment: Just, interesting if there is some option to generate name for new literal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot generate a dynamic variable name with the `var` keyword. But, instead, you can have an object, which can hold these new variables with dynamically generated names:

```js
let object = {};
let n = 3;
let m = 3;

for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; i <= m; i++) {
    object['' + i + j] = document.createElement("div");
  }
}

console.log(object);
```

So, after your loop completes, the `object` with have the elements, each having a unique key under `object`.

Comment: Nice, Thank you!